# Open links in new window using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to tell AngularJS that I want links to be opened in new windows when the user clicks on them?

With jQuery I would do this:

```
jQuery("a.openInNewWindow").click( function() {
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
})
```

Is there an equivalent with AngularJS?

Answer (score 77):

Here's a directive that will add `target="_blank"` to all `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute. That means they will all open in a new window. Remember that directives are used in Angular for any dom manipulation/behavior. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AXanuFEN/33/edit)**

```
app.directive('href', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      element.attr('target', '_blank');
    }
  };
});
```

Here's the same concept made less invasive (so it won't affect all links) and more adaptable. You can use it on a parent element to have it affect all children links. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AYUneQUc/1/edit)**

```
app.directive('targetBlank', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      var elems = (element.prop("tagName") === 'A') ? element : element.find('a');
      elems.attr("target", "_blank");
    }
  };
});
```

#### Old Answer

It seems like you would just use `"target="_blank"` on your `<a>` tag. Here are two ways to go:

```
<a href="//facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
<button ng-click="foo()">Facebook</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.foo = function() {
    $window.open('//facebook.com');
  };
});
```

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AXanuFEN/2/edit)

Here are the docs for `$window`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window

You could just use `window`, but it is better to use dependency injection, passing in angular's `$window` for testing purposes.

Comment: is there any way to get this to work on html inserted using `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: I'm not sure. My guess is that directives won't work in ng-bind-html for security purposes.

Comment: `$timeout(function() {
  $('.content a').attr('target', '_blank') 
}, 0)`

Comment: And if you wanted to tie this into an `$http` promise?

Comment: @Snekse Your question isn't specific enough to answer, but it sounds like something you should use `ui-router` for.

Answer (score 46):

It works for me.
Inject `$window` service in to your controller.

```
$window.open("somepath/", "_blank")
```

Comment: That's the angular way I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 38):

you can use:

```
$window.open(url, windowName, attributes);
```

Comment: although you use $window like angular expects, this answer really doesn't include how to bind, which is part of ops question (it doesn't show how to convert `jQuery(..)` thinking to ng.

Answer (score 11):

this is the code of your button

```
<a href="AddNewUserAdmin" 
   class="btn btn-info " 
   ng-click="showaddnewuserpage()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add User</a>
```

in the controller just add this function.

```
 var app = angular.module('userAPP', []);

app.controller('useraddcontroller', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

$scope.showaddnewuserpage = function () {

    $window.location.href = ('/AddNewUserAdmin');
}

});
```

Answer (score 4):

@m59 Directives will work for ng-bind-html you just need to wait for `$viewContentLoaded` to finish

```
app.directive('targetBlank', function($timeout) {
  return function($scope, element) {
    $scope.initializeTarget = function() {
      return $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', $timeout(function() {
        var elems;
        elems = element.prop('tagName') === 'A' ? element : element.find('a');
        elems.attr('target', '_blank');
      }));
    };
    return $scope.initializeTarget();

  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small gist which I think can be very helpful to anybody seeking a solution to that problem: [external link](https://gist.github.com/idanen/284eb2b6c7efbaecb9b7)

What it does is it adds `target="_blank"` attributes to anchor elements that would link to a domain different than the current one. 
You can patch it up to whatever you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through many links but this answer helped me alot:

`$scope.redirectPage = function (data) {
   $window.open(data, "popup", "width=1000,height=700,left=300,top=200");
 };`

** data will be absolute url which you are hitting.