# How to open new tab in browser by using $location, angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have controller `'reportCtrl'` and HTML that represents 6 tables with data and only several rows I show at once.

**app.js**

```
var appReport = angular.module('myAppReport', []);

appReport.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/showreport', {templateUrl: 'app/reports/reportsView.html', controller: 'reportCtrl'});
            $routeProvider.when('/showreport/:type', {templateUrl: 'app/reports/reportsView.html', controller: 'reportCtrl'});
```

Each table has one button that on click, should open new tab in browser with extended table:

```
scope.onClick = function(path){
    var real_path = $location.path() + '/' + path + '/';
    $location.path( real_path );
    // $window.open($location.path()); // doesn't work
};
```

For example I have root view URL:

```
http://dev.test.com/reports/date/#/showreport
```

Now, after button is pressed I want to create :

```
http://dev.test.com/reports/date/#/showreport/table_name
```

and open it in new tab. As you see, I tried `$window.open($location.path());` but it doesn't work, nothing happens.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: you are confusing angular path, which comes after the hash in url, with a full url

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain? Did I write this wrong? thanks

Comment: `$window.open` should work. Are you injecting the `$window` service properly? You can also try calling it like this: `$window.open(real_path,'_blank');`. Please provide more info/code or a plunk so we can get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: `window` and `$window` are not different too much. If you can't use $window, you can try like `var win=window.open(real_path , '_blank');`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20099784/584846

Answer (score 27):

You are opening a new window using another function which could get Angular confused.

Try passing the string in the `$window.open(real_path)` where real_path is a string containing the path you want to navigate

Comment: Welcome to SO. Be a bit more specific with your code examples, with corrected code from the actual question.

Comment: Can you explain how that would get angular confused?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to open angular page in a new tab on ctrl+click or in same tab, then try this :-

HTML :

```
<a ng-click="navigationUrl($event)">My Link</a>
```

JS:

```
    var navigationUrl = function (event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey) {
                window.open(url, '_blank'); // in new tab
            } else {
                $location.path(url); // in same tab
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 6):

One more option is to use ng-href

HTML:

```
 <a  ng-href="#/courses/{{employee.courseId}}/employees/{{employee.id}}" 
      target="_blank"> {{employee.employeeNumber}}
 </a>
```

Where url is based on where you want to redirect

Comment: will this work if I right click and select "open link in new tab"?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal yes

Answer (score 2):

For opening a new view in a new window, execute the following code:

```
window.open($location.$$absUrl.replace($location.$$path,NEW_PATH), '_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the most voted answer here may work for most scenarios, I want to add the way I found to achieve what OP wants (I needed this as well):

```
var viewPath = '/InsideMyView';
var currentPath = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
var fullPath = currentPath + viewPath;
$window.open(fullPath, '_blank');
```

---

**Explanation**: You just need to obtain the root URL for your app, and you can make use of `#` in the url (which is added by angular), then concatenate the view path to obtain the full url.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

HTML:
`<div ng-click="OpenBrowserInNewTab(someKeyValue)"</div>Click Me </div>`

The Controller:

```
`$scope.OpenBrowserInNewTab = (someKeyValue) ->
    tabWindowId = window.open('/abcdef/ghijk/' + someKeyValue + '', _blank')

    $http.post("/abcdef/ghijk/#someKeyValue", data).then (response) ->
        tabWindowId.location.href = response.headers('Location')
        return
    return`
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening view in new tab with angular parameter

```
   <a  target="_blank" class="btn" data-ng-href="@Url.Action("Hotel", "Home")?hotelCode={{hotel.code}}"> Click Hear</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
window.open(yourURL+'create-account',)
```

`window.open` by default open link in new tab

Comment: Why should he try that? What does that do?

Comment: `window.open` by default open link in new tab