# Open URL in new tab with specific route but not domain.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to open a link in new tab in angular, but as it is a SPA, if I open any link in new tab (right click > open link in new tab) then the site is opened in a new tab (www.domain.com) but not with the specific route (www.domain.com/some_route).

The link which I want to open in new tab gets the route from the controller using `$location.path` in `ng-click`. I cannot use href attribute in the .

Example HTML:

```
<a ng-click="myCustomPath()">Click Me</a>
```

Example JS (controller):

```
$scope.myCustomPath = function(id, slug){
    $location.path('/some_route/id/slug');
}
```

I don't want to open the link in new using controller or any other js logic. No redirection, no $window.open or anything.

Long story short, I want to open "www.domain.com/some_route/id/slug" just by right clicking on the link.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819399/how-to-open-new-tab-in-browser-by-using-location-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open new tab in browser by using $location, angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819399/how-to-open-new-tab-in-browser-by-using-location-angular)

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam, no this is not a duplicate question. In the above link (which you shared), he wants to open a link in new tab by clicking on the link. I don't want to do that. If I left click the link then it open on the same page but if I right click on the link and select "open link in new tab" then I want the specific route. Do you understand my problem or should I rephrase it?

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam, read the problem statement carefully before declaring it a duplicate.

Comment: first of all i am so sorry i misunderstood you it is my bad .
i think what you are looking for is this         

    $scope.myCustomPath = function(){
        $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self');

}

Comment: I resolved the issue using ng-href