# How to open new window (tab) in AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have ASP.NET application where we use AngularJS. The issue is when we click "edit" the new view is openinig in the same window (tab). How to open it in new window (tab)? Here's the code:

List.html:

```
<td><a ng-click="editUser(u.ID)">edit</a></td>
```

AngularJS:

```
AdminUsersApp.controller("ListController", function ($scope, $location, $http, ErrorUI, Users, Cashdesks) {

...


$scope.editUser = function (id) {
    $location.path("/edit/" + id);
};
```

Comment: Did you try `window.open("/edit/" + id);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs

Comment: @Nilesh:

It doesn't work because there is some path got by $location.path.

Comment: If you have to show a different HTML file then use `window.open`. What is `/edit/' + id; is it a URL to some different html?

Comment: The first url is:

http://example.com/admin/Admin_Users.aspx#/list

From that url we click "edit" and should go to:

http://example.com/admin/Admin_Users.aspx#/edit/id

Comment: `$location.path` just returns the path of current page. instead you need the url which actually points to a different location, so when you call window s open function it should have `window.open('example.com/admin/Admin_Users.aspx#/edit/id')`. If you want to build the url dynamically use `$location.host()`, `$location.protocol()` etc to build a url and then append `/edit/id` at the end.

Comment: @Nilesh: I already did it in the meantime. If you want, please, write your last comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$location.path just returns the path of current page. instead you need the url which actually points to a different location, so when you call window s open function it should have window.open('example.com/admin/Admin_Users.aspx#/edit/id'). If you want to build the url dynamically use $location.host(), $location.protocol() etc to build a url and then append /edit/id at the end

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
$window.open(url);
```

Comment: What should be url in my case?