# Open new link in native browser Webapp - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, web-applications

I have a webapp function in javascript that should open an external link in safari (iOS).

Using:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

The page is opening in the same window.

I'm trying `window.open` method but nothing happens.

I have tried this:

```
window.open(
  'https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An alternative if you're specifically looking for an Angular solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs

Comment: Often time the browser will prevent pop-ups, mobile safari is the worst offender of this.  Check to make sure you do not have pop-up blocked and or it is not prompting you to allow/show the pop-up at runtime when you trigger this action