# I like to open a new window (not in the same window) in AngularJs with window.open Without Popup blocker?

Tags: angularjs

I like to open a new window (not in the same window) in AngularJs with window.open on rollover (without click event) and it gets blocked by popup blocker in Google Chrome. Is there a workaround for this?

Because user needs to do only Click action.He doesn't wants to modify browser settings.

Please help me with this.....

Comment: Popup blocker will not block your popup if you fire `window.open` on a user action (like click or dblclick)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs Might be your answer

Comment: if (downloadDoc != undefined) {
                    if (downloadDoc.indexOf("data:image/jpeg;base64,") > -1 || downloadDoc.indexOf("data:image/png;base64,") > -1) {
                        //window.open(downloadDoc);
                        PrintImage(downloadDoc);
                    }
                    else if (downloadDoc.indexOf("data:application/pdf;base64,") > -1) {
                        window.open(downloadDoc);
                    }
                }

Comment: I am trying this but Pop up is blocking .Can someone kindly help.Am new to this .